# How to find the port number in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: sockets, tcp, ubuntu-12.04, command-line-arguments, port-number

I need to write my first socket program involving TCP connections. In the program I have created there is a client and server, both of which are the machine I am coding on.However,it requires that I pass the port number as a command line argument. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: That would depend on the server's port. It should be defined when the server is configured.

Comment: The server and client are basically 2 C programming language files. already have the C codes for the server and client. But to run them on my pc, I need to provide the port number. How do I find that port number?

Comment: When you setup the server, you have to mention the port. Depending on what type of library you use, the line would look like : servaddr.sin_port=htons(32000);    32000 being the port number.

Comment: these are the libraries in the programme                                                #include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

Comment: Here's an example using these libraries http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~almeroth/classes/W01.176B/hw2/examples/tcp-server.c

Comment: Thanks. But then, there is a another confusion. Some of the videos i was referring to are passing numbers like 4547, and they are using the same libraries.What is the reason behind this discrepancy?

Comment: Simply because the port used can vary. The are an array of port that can be used depending on what is to be done. Since a lot of ports are mostly un-used, you can use pretty much the port of your choice. You can see the available port here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

Comment: So basically I can put in any port number of my choice which is not in the list but within the range and get the accurate output?

Comment: As long as both the server and the client agrees with it. Make sure to check the list I sent you. Some ports are used in critical applications and should never be used in third party applications.

Comment: Thank you :).I was so confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple : Make sure your server and your client agree on the port to use. As long as the port is available and can be used, set up the connected so that the client and server use that same port.

Here's [a link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) that explain the different ranges available for TCP and UDP ports.

As an exemple, the port 3074 is used by microsoft for its Xbox live service. Making an application using this port might interfere with the service.

The port used will be defined either in a configuration file or hard-coded in the source code of both the server and the client. You should easily be able to find it with a quick look at the code or the directory which contains the application.

Comment: Thanks :) . This is the first time I'm working on such a program.

Comment: No problem. Consider yourself lucky to use Linux! Microsoft Winsock are a bit more difficult to understand at first glance!